# how we submit php variable values with string in to database using php

Tags: php

I want to submit drop-down with dynamic value. I concatenate all variables  inside the string but data not submit any one help me how is it done

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
     $value2 = $_POST['value2'];


        $data = "<select name=''$name''>";
        $data .="<option>Selet data</option>";
        $data .="<option value='**$value1**'> **$value1**</option>";
        $data .="<option value='**$value2**'> **$value2**</option>";
        $data .="</select>";

        mysql_query("insert into options (value) values ('".$data."')");
    }
```

With variable string not submit in to the database.

HTML is below

```
<form action="" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="text" name="value1">
        <input type="text" name="value2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: show us please the full code and your html part... btw dont use `mysql_` functions they are deprecated since php 5.5.0

Comment: You want to insert the whole shebang, including HTML tags? Or just the values?

Comment: Do query the database for errors. $data WILL contain illegal characters in the context of your query.

Comment: "How it is done" is to use prepared statements and query parameters.  What you're building here is one great big SQL syntax error.  `mysql_error()` is undoubtedly telling you about the problem, you should check that for errors.  While not necessarily a duplicate, this would be a great place for you to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Check your table field strength

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting html code in a mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371093/inserting-html-code-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Also you have an extra `}`.

Comment: i want to insert HTML tags with php variable values

Comment: I still don't understand what you wanna achieve or why you doing this

Comment: i remove the extra }

Comment: i want to submit a string with php variable values ...but when i use php variable inside the string then data not submit

Comment: what datatype are you using, you have to use htmlspecialchars

Comment: no i can not using

Comment: @shan -please echo the query and directly paste to database and let us know its working or not

Comment: @shan can you please show us the html form too?

Comment: i echo the query value show inside query but value not submit it give the syntax error like Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*`value**'> **`value****value**

Comment: Buddy my table field strength is 1000 with varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with below:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
     $value2 = $_POST['value2'];

        $data = "<select name='$name'>";
        $data .="<option>Selet data</option>";
        $data .="<option value='**$value1**'> **$value1**</option>";
        $data .="<option value='**$value2**'> **$value2**</option>";
        $data .="</select>";

        if(!mysql_query("insert into options (`value`) values (".json_encode($data).")")) {
          echo("Error description: " . mysql_error());
        }
}
```