# How insert article to mysql column - htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, mysql

How to properly log out an easy html code to a database to make it secure? I have  lift and I am getting html code. If I use htmlspecialchars, I'll throw in & gt; e.t.c.

How to do it correctly and safely?

I would like to add that every user can insert articles.

Ok, I added: mysqli_real_escape_string + trim to remove unnecessary white characters. The html code is thrown into the database. This is ok? I added  alert (1);  and the code was done. How to prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting html code in a mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371093/inserting-html-code-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: check this function [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `real_escape_string()` to insert HTML Code it will treat your whole html code as string and allow special charecters to get inserted for more info you can check manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Ok, I added: mysqli_real_escape_string + trim to remove unnecessary white characters. The html code is thrown into the database. This is ok? I added <script> alert (1); </ script> and the code was done. How to prevent this?